# find a formula for $S(n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $S(n) =\sum\tau(d)\sigma^2(d)$, where the sum is taken over all divisors $d$ of $n$.

How to find a formula for $S(n)$ in terms of the prime factorization of $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you want to demonstrate that it is multiplicative, i.e. $S(nm)=S(n)S(m)$ whenever $gcd(n,m)=1$. Assume that $n,m$ are coprime integers.

$$S(nm)=\sum_{d|nm}\tau(d)\sigma(d)^2 $$

But now $\{d\text{ dividing } nm\}=\{d_1d_2|d_1\text{ divides } n\text{ and } d_2\text{ divides }m\}$.

Then :

$$S(nm)=\sum_{d_1|n}\sum_{d_2|m}\tau(d_1d_2)\sigma_2(d_1d_2) $$

Now I assume that $\tau$ is the number of divisors, and $\sigma^2=\sigma_2$ their square-sum.From the equality of sets above it easily follows that $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are also multiplicative, and because $gcd(d_1,d_2)=1$ you have :

$$S(nm)=\sum_{d_1|n}\sum_{d_2|m}\tau(d_1)\tau(d_2)\sigma_2(d_1)\sigma_2(d_2) $$

$$S(nm)=\sum_{d_1|n}\tau(d_1)\sigma_2(d_1)\sum_{d_2|m}\tau(d_2)\sigma_2(d_2)=S(n)S(m)$$

This shows that $gcd(n,m)=1$ implies $S(nm)=S(n)S(m)$. Now, using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic $n>1$ is always a product of $p^k$ with $p$ primes and $k>0$. Assume :

$$n=p_1^{k_1}...p_r^{k_r} $$

Then :

$$S(n)=S(p_1^{k_1})...S(p_r^{k_r}) $$

The last thing to do is to compute $S(p^k)$ for each $p$ and $k$. Divisors of $p^k$ are $p^i$ with $0\leq i\leq k$ so :

$$S(p^k)=\sum_{i=0}^k\tau(p^i)\sigma_2(p^i) $$

We have :

$$\tau(p^i)=i+1 $$

$$\sigma_2(p^i)=\sum_{l=0}^{i}p^{2l}=\frac{p^{2i+2}-1}{p^2-1} $$

$$S(p^k)=\frac{1}{p^2-1}\sum_{i=0}^k(i+1)(p^{2i+2}-1)$$

$$S(p^k)=\frac{1}{p^2-1}(\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i(p^2)^i-\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}i)$$

$$S(p^k)=\frac{1}{p^2-1}(\frac{(k+1)p^{2k+6}-(k+2)p^{2k+4}+p^2}{(p^2-1)^2}-\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2})$$